# How to set creating google doc in gdrive using PHP as read only file

Tags: php, google-drive-api, file-permissions, google-api-php-client

I am creating a `txt/html` file in google drive as document using the google drive sdk. the code creates successfully the document. 
My question is that it is possible that it can also set the file permission as `read-only` file?

this is my code in creating the document,

`$mkFile = $this->_service->files->insert($file, array('data' => $subcontent, 'mimeType' => 'text/html', 'convert' => true));`

Answer (score 1):

You can create Permission to Anyone only reader.

Code based from documentation Google Drive API V3:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create

```
public function permissionAnyone($fileId) {

  $permissions = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
     'role' => 'reader',
     'type' => 'anyone',
  ));

  try {
     $result = $this->service_drive->permissions->create($fileId, $permissions);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
     $result = $e->getMessage();
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [permissions.patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/patch) to update the permissions for a file after it has been inserted.   There is currently a bug in the API that doesn't allow you to set the permissions at the time you insert the file.  You have to patch them after the file has been placed on drive.

Code ripped from documentation link above.

```
/**
 * Patch a permission's role.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param String $fileId ID of the file to update permission for.
 * @param String $permissionId ID of the permission to patch.
 * @param String $newRole The value "owner", "writer" or "reader".
 * @return Google_Servie_Drive_Permission The patched permission. NULL is
 *     returned if an API error occurred.
 */
function patchPermission($service, $fileId, $permissionId, $newRole) {
  $patchedPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
  $patchedPermission->setRole($newRole);
  try {
    return $service->permissions->patch($fileId, $permissionId, $patchedPermission);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: where can I get the `$permissionId` value?